# Cómo compilar TypeScript en el navegador

Tags: typescript

Buen día comunidad, estoy aprendiendo typescript debido a que me pidieron en las prácticas de empresa que lo aprenda pero estoy teniendo un problema bastante molesto y es que ningún navegador (brave, edge y chrome) me reconoce el código. 
Por ejemplo: 
 `let nombre:string = "tobias";` 
  La consola me dice que los dos puntos no son válidos así que los quité, pero ahora también llegué a enumeraciones y cuando hago  por ejemplo 
 `enum Volumen{ min, medio, max }` me dice que enum es una palabra reservada y que está mal utilizada.
Estoy usando el watcher que me ofrece tsc -w y por la terminal del IDE está todo en orden pero en los navegadores me tira errores por cualquier cosa que sea de typescript...
Hay que realizar alguna configuración adicional?

Comment: Hola, dado a que ts es un lenguaje compilado, no es soportado por los navegadores, tienes que transpilar el código cada vez que quieras usarlo, es decir en lugar de usar el archivo ts usa el output Js que te dé tsc compile, por otro lado si quieres algo que corra ya nativamente usa deno que es un runtime para JavaScript y typescript, nativamente, sin compilar y todo eso, un saludo.

Comment: Bienvenido a stackoverflow, Tobias, vas a pasar mucho tiempo aquí (si es que todavía no visitabas aquí para dudas)  ¿A qué versión de ES estás compilando? Revisa en el tsconfig, busca `compilerOptions` y comprueba la propiedad `target`, creo recordar que los navegadores soportan hasta ES6 así que debes usar una versión que sea compatible.

Comment: Buenas, siempre que quieras aprender algo lo recomendable es ir a la documentación oficial. Si quieres correr una aplicación deTypeScript, la idea es utilizarlo en un editor de código como VS Code.

Comment: Gracias por responder, el problema fue que tenía linkeado el archivo ts en vez del js

Answer (score 0):

Typescript es un lenguaje que añade funcionalidades a Javascript. Es un superconjunto estricto de Javascript, lo que quiere decir que cualquier código válido escrito en Javascript es código válido en Typescript... pero no al revés.

Una vez que tienes Typescript instalado en tu computadora, tienes que usar el compilador para generar el código Javascript que los navegadores o NodeJS pueden ejecutar correctamente. Esto significa usar Babel o tsc. Para cosas sencillas recomiendo usar tsc, ya que su uso es muy sencillo:

```
> tsc mi-fichero.ts
```

Esto generará, si no hay errores de compilación, un fichero `mi-fichero.js`